# Does clicking an iOS iAd pause new ads from being fetched?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, iad, ads

When an iAd banner is clicked, and the interactive ad *doesn't* leave the app, are ads still received by the app while the full screen ad is displayed? Or is receiving new ads suspended at this time?

It doesn't say either way in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/ADBannerViewDelegate/bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:).

I ask because I want to give the app every chance to optimize the CTR (click-through rate), so I'm wondering if I should stop ads manually like this:

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner
               willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave {
    if(!willLeave) {
        [self destroyAdBanner]; // to stop receiving new ads
    }        
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self createAdBanner];  // start receiving new ads again if not already
}
```

What is the official approach? An Apple reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just set a breakpoint in `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` and see if it's hit while a full-screen ad is open?

Comment: @remus It's a brand new project. No code yet. I get asked, so I then ask, but nothing found on Google.

Comment: I'd spend a few minutes, whip up a new project, and test it out. My guess says that it will be paused while the full-screen is displayed, otherwise there would be some odd behavior when the delegate methods are called.

Comment: I'm putting out other fires at the moment, so I can wire something up and test it in a few days time, but I'm hoping someone knows an Apple ref I can reference myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official documentation that I can find, but from repeated trials after an ad banner is clicked and the full-screen ad appears and waiting for long periods of time, there are no further calls to *any* of the ad delegate methods until the user interaction terminates. It looks like no new ads are fetched while in user interaction mode.